# Communication between Contour Next Link 2.4 and insulin pump MiniMed 640G

Tags: diabetes, type-1-diabetes, insulin

I am wondering how the Contour Next Link 2.4 and the insulin pump MiniMed 640G communicate with each other. Is this over Bluetooth or what is it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pump MiniMed 640G and the Contour Next Link 2.4 uses the IEEE 802.15.4 protocol with a proprietary data format.

It uses the following operating frequencies 2420 MHz, 2435 MHz, 2450 MHz, 2465 MHz, 2480 MHz with a 5 MHz Bandwidth.

There is yet no evidence of the compatibility of the MiniMed Connect with the 640g.

If you're interesting in the communication with your pump you can check this project that allows you to get data from your pump on Android Phones using the Contour Next Link 2.4: https://github.com/pazaan/600SeriesAndroidUploader

Source:
https://www.medtronic-diabetes.co.uk/sites/uk/medtronic-diabetes.co.uk/files/minimed640gifu2015mp6025957-024_a_en_mmol.compressed.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer touts its ability to transmit data to its own apps via Bluetooth, so I'd say the answer is yes.

> The MiniMed Connect App for iOS is compatible for devices running iOS
>   8 and iOS 9 with Bluetooth®

.

> The MiniMed Connect App for OS is compatible for devices running
>   Android™5.0/5.1.1/5.1.2 (Lollipop) and Android™ 6.0/6.0.1/6.0.2
>   (Marshmallow) with Bluetooth®.

https://www.medtronicdiabetes.com/products/minimed-connect